# Help me with this definition of Anti-symmetric relationships

Tags: discrete-mathematics

First, forgive for my English, I don't speak this Language.

The the definition of *anti-symmetric* relationships says:

> $(a,b) ∈ R \land (b,a) ∈ R ⇒ a = b$;

I really don't understand what this means, so can somebody explain to me what this means in a more "intuitive" way and show me examples so that I can understand this ?

Comment: See [Antisymmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) : "The usual order relation ≤ on the real numbers is anti-symmetric: if for two real numbers x and y both inequalities x ≤ y and y ≤ x hold then x and y must be equal."

Comment: "the divisibility order on the natural numbers is an anti-symmetric relation. And what anti-symmetry means here is that the only way each of two numbers can be divisible by the other is if the two are, in fact, the same number; equivalently, if n and m are distinct and n is a factor of m, then m cannot be a factor of n."

Comment: Downvoting; you already have the name of the definition, why can't you search for it on Google? Or _have_  you already searched? Maybe you could state where this statement come from, and if you have searched already, and if you have found a definition in which you don't understand, state it in the question?

Comment: What a stupid reason to downvote.  If the OP doesn't understand a question and asks for help, just telling him/her to reread the definition until he/she does isn't helpful.

Comment: @fleablood, why do you always seem to criticise me?  Is it because I'm a child? Also, hovering over the downvote button gives the text "lack of research", which in this case fits almost perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume when I write about $a$ and I write about $b$ that $a \ne b$.

Symetric means:  If $(a,b) \in R$ then $(b,a) \in R$ (for every possible $a,b$ where $(a,b) \in R$).

Anti-symetric means: If $(a,b) \in R$ then $(b,a) \not \in R$.  Not ever.   If $(a,b) \in R$ and $a \ne b$ then it will *NEVER* be the case that $(b,a) \in R$.

There is one exception. If $(a,a) \in R$ then... $(a,a) \in R$.  If $a = b$ then if $(a,b) = (a,a) =(b,b)=(b,a)\in R$ because $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are the same thing.

But if $a \ne b$.  **anti-symmetric** means a relation is *never* symmetric (for unequal values).

====

The best example is "$\ge$".   $(a,b) \in R \iff $a \le b$.  So if $a \le b$ and $b \le a$ that is *only* possible if $a = b$.

Basically, if $a \ne b$ then, if $a < b$ then $b \not \le a$.  $a \le b$ and $b \le a$ are mutually exclusive *unless* $a = a$.

Also "$<$" is also anti-reflexive.  If $a < b$ then $b < a $ is impossible.  But as $a \not < a$, we don't have to worry about the case were $a = b$ and $(a,a) \in R$ because $(a,a)$ will never be in $R$.

====

Answer (score 1):

Think of it the following way:
$$(a,b)\in R\Longrightarrow(b,a)\notin R$$

Comparing it to the definition of symmetry you can see, that's an anti-symmetric relationship which contains $$(a,b)$$ but does **not** contain $$(b,a)$$ So if $$(a,b)\in R \text{ }\wedge\text{ }(b,a)\in R$$ it becomes a necessity for $a$ and $b$ to have the same value!

Here's an example:
"A is wedded to B" is a symmetric relationship, but "A is the father of B" not, because B can't be the father of A if A is the father of B, right?